# Image throw 502 error on same domain Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js, config

My website is at example.com and I have an image at `example.com/images/myimage.png` (images folder is inside the `/public` folder.

I am trying to load that image on my website; For example

```js
<Image
   src={`${host}/images/myimage.png`}... />
```

with ${host} being http://localhost or https://example.com on production

My `next.config.js`:

```
        domains: [
            "localhost:3000",
            "localhost",
            "example.com"
        ],
```

It works perfectly on localhost (images load fine) but fails on production via Vercel;

All I get is a 502 Error with `OPTIMIZED_EXTERNAL_IMAGE_REQUEST_UNAUTHORIZED` as error code.

Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?